# GTK+3.0 - Scrollbar on Treeview/ScrolledWindow - CSS properties to control scrollbar

Tags: gtk3

Developing on GTK+3.0 (3.22.30), openbox on X11, Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I've have been struggling to figure out the CSS model to control the appearance of the scrollbar on a GtkTreeView ScrolledWindow.  I have had very limited success.  The only thing I have been able to control is the color of the slider when clicking/moving on it and the background color of the trough.  The other properties don't seem to have any effect.  I found that the color property of the trough is not supported and seems to cause a parsing error.

The application uses a touch screen so I need the scroll bar to appear all the time, not just when a cursor-pointer hovers over the control.  There is no cursor-pointer in the touch application.

I have tried these CSS definitions below. Some of this is simply experimental trying to get something to work.  I've tried moving the width, min-width and the 'has-xx-stepper' but they don't seem to have any effect.  I'm still stuck with the same simple default slider but with some basic color control.  I can't interpret how the CSS node model for a scrollbar is to be referenced as I can't find an example.

```
scrollbar {
  has-backwards-stepper: true;
  has-forward-stepper: true;
  has-secondary-backward-stepper: true;
  has-secondary-forward-stepper: true;
  min-width: 80;
}

trough {
 background-color: #00ee00;
}

slider {
 color: #00FF00;
 slider-width: 80;
 min-width: 80;
 has-backwards-stepper: true;
 has-forward-stepper: true;
}
```

Using the GTK+ Inspector (which allows some examination of Gtk apps' CSS attributes) I can't find the 'has-backwards-stepper' and other properties as referenced in the GTK3 GtkScrollbar documentation.  This is handy place to test the CSS syntax but I can't figure out how to control the appearance as I need.

What is the syntax that I should be using to get the stepper buttons, to fix the width and have it appear at all times?  A pointer to the documentation that explains this would be helpful. I've already been through the GTK 3 CSS Overview exhaustively which is no help here.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a possible solution to this?  Maybe the integrated scroll bar can't perform as required?  Any constructive suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to determine that the `has-xxxx-stepper` properties appear to be read only but don't actually connect to anything as I can change.

I was able to get the scrollbar to appear to the right of the scrollwindow with the 'overlay-scrolling' property.

```
sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_container_set_border_width( GTK_CONTAINER(sw), 0 );
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), TK_POLICY_NEVER, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS ); //scroll bars
//Set scrollbar to ALWAYS be displayed and not as temporary overlay
g_object_set( sw , "overlay-scrolling", FALSE , NULL);
```

I was able to further control the width of the scrollbar trough with this:

```
GtkWidget * ptrVscrollBar = gtk_scrolled_window_get_vscrollbar ( TK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw) );    
g_object_set( ptrVscrollBar ,
                "width-request", 30 ,
                "margin-bottom", 30 ,
                "margin-top", 30 ,
                NULL);
```

Update: I found the that CSS syntax was a little different for the slider.  With some experimentation I was able to override the width and height of the slider component.  The `px` units are required for these property values and without them they are ignored.

```
slider {
  min-width: 28px;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

I have not figured out how to enable the stepper buttons to appear. Do these now have to be manually / separately created with GTK3?  I have some prototype code using the `vadjustment` object properties of the scroll window but what a pain to hook up for every scroll bar I have.

Comment: I have this exact problem. Because the properties are read-only, they refuse to be set, so the stepper buttons cannot be enabled.